# remove last substring from string

Tags: regex, sed, tcl

I would like  to remove the last subsrting from string.
the **pattern** of string is :

```
str1.str2.strn-1.{i}.strn
```

and the desired result is :

```
str1.str2.strn-1.{i}.
```

I tried with shell
`echo $str |sed -e 's/\.*$//'` but it doesn't work

what is the best method to do that

Comment: I don't know `sed` but `\.*$` in regex means "*the character `.` matched 0 to infinity times at the immediate end of a string*". Try `\.[\.]+$` (*the character `.` followed by any character that ISN'T `.` repeated 1 to infinity times at the immediate end of a string*). Note that this will strip off your last `.` (which, according to your desired result, is not correct)

Answer (score 3):

The `-e` switch is to add editing command. You only have 1 command so there's no need to use it. Instead, you want the `-E` flag to tell `sed` to use modern regular expression. Try this:

```
echo $str | sed -E 's/[^.]+$//'
```

`[^.]+$` matches any character between the last dot and end of line.

Answer (score 1):

A short, simple solution that uses standard sed, without using extended regular expressions:

```
sed 's/[^.]*$//'
```

which says to remove every non-dot character from the end of the line. A few things to note:

1. Typically a dot (aka period) means "any character," but inside a bracket expression, it matches only a literal dot, so there's no need to escape it with a backslash.
2. Asterisk means "match zero or more," and by default the asterisk is greedy, meaning it will match as many characters as it can.

So the command says to replace as many non-dots as possible at the end of the line with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with tcl

```
regsub -- {[^.]+$} $str {} string
```

`[^.]+$` match the last '.' appended with any string at the end of $str

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the fact that strings are **dot**-separated.
Here is a pure Tcl solution (`s` is original string):

```
set s "[file rootname $s]."
```

or

```
set s [file rootname $s]
append s "."
```

According to file(n) manpage, `file rootname` returns

> ...all of the characters in name up to but not including the last “.” character in the last component of name. If the last component of name does not contain a dot, then returns name